# Proper way to detect that post_max_size was exceded in php?

Tags: php, file-upload

What is the proper way to detect that post_max_size was exceded in php?  It looks like I can only check for an empty $_POST array, which seems imprecise.  I need to detect if a file that was uploaded was to big and produce a proper error message.

Comment: The `$_FILES` array [will contain an error message](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) if the maximum *file* size is exceeded. Not sure what happens if `post_max_size` breaks

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Both `$_FILES` and `$_POST` [become empty](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size).

Answer (score 2):

You can't, if the value of post_max_size is exceeded, super globals will be empty.

A solution is to add in your form a $_GET variable

```
<form action="check.php?shouldHaveFilesInHere">
```

and to check if other super globals are filled or not in check.php.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the file that was uploaded is too large you should use $_FILE['error'].

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: the $_FILES (not $_FILE) array is blank as well, so this doesn't work.

Comment: No you can't check if the file was to large (due to post_max_size) in $_FILES['error'] as super globals will be empty. It would have worked with upload_max_filesize  though.